# IO Completion Listener (0x1814) Worker 0x0000000000A021A0 appears to be non-yielding on Node 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ello StackOverflow,

We have recently had a situation where our production database (MSSQL 2008 R2) server fell over and we saw this error thousands of time in the error log.

IO Completion Listener (0x1814) Worker 0x0000000000A021A0 appears to be non-yielding on Node 0. Approx CPU Used: kernel 0 ms, user 0 ms, Interval: 20233954.

Has anyone ever seen this before or could provide some advice to begin looking into it.

We ran a big performance test against the instance about 24 hours before we started seeing the error.

Kin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a a mixture of bug/feature :)  [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2216485) the kb article has the steps to mitigate the issue. Your performance test soaked ups and didn't release a lot of resource and the resource governor is working on cleaning it up. The message is informational. There is more/better detail on the KB article; it should be fixed in SP2 if you haven't installed that.

Comment: Thank you very much after I started searching IO Completion Listener + node I started to find similar stuff. We shall investigate further.